how to change duration of shared element transitions in react native
Im using react native reanimated's sharedTransitionTag to achieve my shared transition and wanted to know how can we change the duration of the animated to make it faster or slower
so far i haven't been able to really think of a solution since im not using any animations ( like withtiming or withspring etc ) .
all i need is just to change the duration on the default animation that comes with sharedTransitionTag in react native reanimated
